# Making sure no integers in a string?

Tags: python, string, integer

I have a simple question. I'm just wanting to know how I would have my program read the "input()" and see if there are integers or any kind of number in the string, and if so then print out a message saying so. Pretty much I just want to know how I would make sure that no one enters in a number for their name. Thanks!

```
yn = None
while yn != "y":
    print("What is your name?")
    name = input()
    print("Oh, so your name is {0}? Cool!".format(name))
    print("Now how old are you?")
    age = input()
    print("So your name is {0} and you're {1} years old?".format(name, age))
    print("y/n?")
    yn = input()
    if yn == "y":
        break
    if yn == "n":
        print("Then here, try again!")
print("Cool!")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`str.isdigit()` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) on strings, together with the [`any()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(c.isdigit() for c in name):
    # there is a digit in the name
```

`.isdigit()` returns `True` for any string that consists only of digits. This includes any Unicode character that is marked as a numeric digit or numeric decimal.

`any()` loops over the sequence you pass in and returns `True` as soon as it finds the first element that is `True`, and `False` if all elements are `False`.

Demo:

```
>>> any(c.isdigit() for c in 'Martijn Pieters')
False
>>> any(c.isdigit() for c in 'The answer is 42')
True
```

Comment: Wouldn't I have to incorporate that along with a while statement? Such as "while name != True", etc?

Comment: @Xiam: No, you don't have to use a `while` statement. The `for .. in ..` statement inside of the `any()` function is called a generator expression, and stands on it's own.

Comment: Well I would like to add in a loop that makes it so the person can't continue through the program without entering in a valid name (I probably should of explained that). And that **would** include having a `while` loop, yes?

Comment: @Xiam: Sure, then you can use a `while` statement too. :-)

Answer (score 3):

*see if there are integers or any kind of number in the string*

```
any(c.isdigit() for c in name)
```

returns `True` for strings such as "123", "123.45", "abc123".

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the strings, regular expressions might actually be faster:

```
import re

s1 = "This is me"
s2 = "this is me 2"
s3 = "3 this is me"

regex = re.compile(r'\d')
import timeit
def has_int_any(s):
    return any(x.isdigit() for x in s)

def has_int_regex(s,regex=re.compile(r'\d')):
    return regex.search(s)

print bool(has_int_any(s1)) == bool(has_int_regex(s1))
print bool(has_int_any(s2)) == bool(has_int_regex(s2))
print bool(has_int_any(s3)) == bool(has_int_regex(s3))


for x in ('s1','s2','s3'):
    print x,"any",timeit.timeit('has_int_any(%s)'%x,'from __main__ import has_int_any,%s'%x)
    print x,"regex",timeit.timeit('has_int_regex(%s)'%x,'from __main__ import has_int_regex,%s'%x)
```

My results are:

```
True
True
True
s1 any 1.98735809326
s1 regex 0.603290081024
s2 any 2.30554199219
s2 regex 0.774269104004
s3 any 0.958808898926
s3 regex 0.656207084656
```

(Note that the regular expression engine wins even in the case specifically designed for `any` to be fastest).  however, with longer strings, I'm willing to bet that `any` will eventually be faster.